# Xamarin Binding will not work with generated observable collection

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, data-binding

My question boils down to why won't my observable collection binding work? I am attempting to bind an image url to a listview, but the binding will not work, pretty much just make a list of product images.  I can generate the image if I just do a stack layout and declare the image based on the list position (ie image.source = list[i].url).

Below is the xaml

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ActImage}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Below is the c behind the xaml where "PicListPull" is the model and pictures is the previously generated list of image urls.

```
    private ObservableCollection<PicListPull> actimage;
    public ObservableCollection<PicListPull> ActImage;
    ActImage = new ObservableCollection<PicListPull>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pictures.Count(); i++)
        {
            var pics = new PicListPull()
            {
                ImageUrl = ImageSource.FromUri(pictures[i].Url)
            };
            ActImage.Add(pics);

        }
```

If I look at the ActImage at an index, it has a value for the image source, so I can't figure out why it won't display the image.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Below is the PicListPull

```
    public class PicListPull:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ImageSource imageurl;
    //#region public properties
    public ImageSource ImageUrl
    {
        get { return imageurl; }
        set
        {
            this.imageurl = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ImageUrl");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(String name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: you can only bind to public properties, `ActImage` is not a property

Comment: and, you an bind the `Source` property to a simple string containing the url, you don't need to manually create an `ImageSource`

Comment: My apologies for being unclear, "ImageUrl" is a property of "PicListPull", shouldn't this binding make the property bind?

Comment: you are using Binding to set the ItemsSource to ActImage, which is not a public property

Comment: have you tried the three changes that @Qwerty and I suggested?

Comment: Not the third yet, but the others haven't worked so far:  included the view cell in xaml and changed imagesource to string.

Comment: you need to do all three of them

Comment: Yep, works now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The cell of ListView should be one of these type :
TextCell, ImageCell, SwitchCell, EntryCell or CustomCell (ViewCell)

In this case if you want to use custom cell then please update like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ActImage}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

For more details you can check here : [Custom Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells)

Answer (score 0):

there are three issues you need to fix

first, you can only bind to public properties

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ActImage}"
```

for this to work, `ActImage` needs to be a public property

```
public ObservableCollection<PicListPull> ActImage { get; set; }
```

second, you need to use a `Cell` in your template (as @Qwerty noted)

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

finally, when binding the `Image`, you can just use a string containing the url